# How to roll up EditText?

Tags: android

I have an `EditText` defined in my half screen `RelativeLayout`. and it appears perfectly. However, if I start typing typing more than 1 line in my `EditText`, it makes my entire entire window expand. I want the `EditText` to roll up and only show the currently typing line? Like in `Facebook Messager`, I want the `EditText` to keep scrolling itself as the user types new lines? HEre is how I implemented the `EditText`

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
```

Comment: then you have to fix a height for your editext.

Comment: you can use android:maxLines="1"

Comment: have u got the solution ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set

```
  android:maxLines="1"
```

This makes the TextView be at most this many lines tall.